# Android: Making a phone call from home screen widget

Tags: android, widget, phone-call

I have a widget and I want it to make a phonecall to a particular number when the user clicks on the widget. How do i do this? Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to get it working with this code:

```
 @Override
 public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onUpdate(): ");
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+number));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, callIntent, 0);

        // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener to the button
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.caller);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.callButton, pendingIntent);

        // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current App Widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
```

Comment: does it work the first time you add the widget? or do you have to launch the app first to trigger an onUpdate?

Comment: it will work the first time. `onUpdate()` is called when you add the widget.

Answer (score 4):

```
    public static Intent newPhoneCallIntent(String phoneNumber){
     Intent callintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
     callintent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phoneNumber));
     return callintent;
    }
    startActivity(newPhoneCallIntent("5555555555"));
```

Comment: where do I add this? In the `onUpdate()` function?

Comment: `startActivity()` throws the error - `The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type Widget`

Comment: @rohith you need to do it from a context. If doing it from a button of some sort try getContext().startActivity()