# Android Intent.CALL not working

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call

I looked at the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181402/android-making-a-phone-call-from-home-screen-widget) and tried to replicate the answer. However,

`Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);` does nothing while

`Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);` brings me to the number pad with the pre-set number.

I want it to call the number without bringing me to the number pad. How do I make it work?

the onUpdate():

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
       Log.d("HomeWidget", "onUpdate(): ");
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+12345678));
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, callIntent, 0);

            // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener to the button
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.call, pendingIntent);

            // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current App Widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
}
```

**Edit**

From the answer below, I see that there are restrictions present on Intent.CALL but i really want to use it. Anyone can help me on how to  lift the restrictions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that all I need is just

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>`

Answer (score 0):

There will be restrictions on which applications can initiate a call using `ACTION_CALL`; most applications should use the `ACTION_DIAL`.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what restrictions are there and how can i remove those restrictions? I don't want to use dial as the widget is used by elderly as a help call, and might press the wrong button in the number pad.

Comment: Probably only system apps can do it, which seems very reasonable. I don't want any app placing calls behind the scenes. There's also ACTION_CALL_PRIVILEGED, but I guess same restrictions apply.