# Make a phone call from Home screen using widgets (multiple onClick)

Tags: android, onclick, widget

I am trying to create a simple widget with three buttons such that when a button is clicked, the appropriate number is dialed from the widget.

I came across this question: [Android: Making a phone call from home screen widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181402/android-making-a-phone-call-from-home-screen-widget) however, the solution described is meant to work for just a button.

I thought of using a switch statement to make the different buttons clickable but failed!

My question is how can i implement that approach to work on more than one button.

Thanks.

My SimpleWidgetProvider.java

```
public class SimpleWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

private static final String MyOnClick1 = "myOnClickTag1";
private static final String MyOnClick2 = "myOnClickTag2";
private static final String MyOnClick3 = "myOnClickTag3";


@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {


    // Get all ids
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, SimpleWidgetProvider.class);
    int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

    for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.simple_widget);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.actionButton, getPendingSelfIntent(context, MyOnClick1));
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.actionButton2, getPendingSelfIntent(context, MyOnClick2));
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.actionButton3, getPendingSelfIntent(context, MyOnClick3));


      /*  Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:192"));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, callIntent, 0);
        // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener to the button

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.actionButton, pendingIntent);*/


        // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current App Widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);

    }
}

protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
    intent.setAction(action);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);//add this line
    if (MyOnClick1.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:192"));
        // your onClick action is here
        Toast.makeText(context, "Button1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.w("Widget", "Clicked button1");
    } else if (MyOnClick2.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:193"));
        Toast.makeText(context, "Button2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.w("Widget", "Clicked button2");
    } else if (MyOnClick3.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:194"));
        Toast.makeText(context, "Button3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.w("Widget", "Clicked button3");
    }
}
```

Comment: make three buttons that each make three different intents

Comment: @petey, i have tried that in my onRecieve method. But still didn't work out! BTW i have included the code in the question. thanks